# Does the jenkinsfile's repo have to be reachable form a worker agent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I have a local git repo with the following Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent none           
  stages {
    stage('hello') {
      agent { label 'aws' }
      steps {
            echo "HELLO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The repo is fine and accessible by Jenkins master, so jobs starts running fine. However, when it hits the stage (assigned to an 'aws' node), it fails because it's not reachable from there- the node is a different network.
If I paste the pipeline in the job config as an inline script, it works fine.
I don't see why Jenkins is trying to clone the Jenkinsfile's repo on a remote node - is there any way to avoid that?

I tried with and without "Lightweight checkout", still getting the same failure:

```
Obtained hello.jenkinsfile from git /home/inger/localci
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (hello)
[Pipeline] node
Running on EC2 (MyAWS) - test-image (i-09de5ed33de7637e5) in /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] checkout
No credentials specified
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from /home/inger/localci
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:908)
...        ..
stderr: fatal: '/home/inger/localci' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
....
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the answer, @zett42 - was searching for similar questions but missed that one :)